# toggle and filter categories using jquery

Tags: jquery, filter, toggle

So i am trying to filter different categories, but I cannot figure how to get the categories to show up on the second click. .not(design) is not allowing me to bring back design (on the second click) after they have been filtered.  I dont want to use a button to display all, id rather just be able to toggle buttons on and off similar to radio buttons.

I hope this makes sense it is a bit difficult for me to put into words.

.web-buttons li and up part of the function work great

A LINK TO JS FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/mWran/1/

$('.design-button').click(function () {

```
 $('.web-buttons li').not(this).removeClass('up')  
 $(this).toggleClass("up")
 $('#webul li').removeClass('clicked')   
 $('#webul li').not('.design').toggleClass('clicked')
```

});

$('.branding-button').click(function () {

```
 $('.web-buttons li').not(this).removeClass('up') 
 $(this).toggleClass("up")  
 $('#webul li').removeClass('clicked')   
 $('#webul li').not('.branding').toggleClass('clicked')
```

});

```
    <div id="web-design-content">
        <ul id="webul">


            <li class="view view-first coding design branding drupal">
            <img src="images/epic-electro.jpg" width="297" height="203" />
            <div class="mask"> 
                     <h2 class="bebas">Epic Electro Music Blog</h2> 
                     <p>Introducing Epic Electro: an electronic music blog showcasing electronic dance music from around the world</p> 

                     <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe info ostrich" href="epicelectro.html">Read More</a>
                 </div>     
            </li>

            <li class="view view-first coding branding">
            <img src="images/soul-of-athens.jpg" width="297" height="203" />
            <div class="mask"> 
                     <h2 class="bebas">2012 Soul Of Athens</h2> 
                     <p>Ohio University multimedia sequence class of 2012 presents Swing State: Ohio's role in the outcome of the presidential election</p> 
                     <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe info ostrich" href="soa.html">Read More</a>
                 </div>     
            </li>




        </ul>



  </div><!-- Endb Web Design content -->
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'd recommend creating a http://jsfiddle.net/ working example for everyone to test from.

Comment: thank you here is a js fiddle! 

http://jsfiddle.net/mWran/1/

Answer (score 0):

The CSS classes are mismatching.

You have a

```
.not('.design')
```

in your JS code, but the class name in the HTML attribute is

```
<li class="design-button even">
```

just change the `.not()`-calls to

```
.not('.design-button')
```

You could also use

```
$('#webul li:not(.design-button)').toggleClass('clicked');
```

as selector.

Comment: Thanks feela, but I am not trying to hide .design-button. .design-button is the button triggering the hiding of the different list items below. If I change it to .not('.design-button') than all of the boxes are hidden. 

I want to be able to hit .design-button and the items are filtered. what i cant figure out is how to hit .design-button again and all the items come back.

http://jsfiddle.net/mWran/1/